# GraphDB Lucene connector - how to edit

Tags: lucene, graphdb

Is there a way to edit existing Lucene Connectors in GraphDB's workbench? The provided buttons are only for rebuilding, copying and dropping a connector.

Answer (score 1):

You may use copy connector to edit existing one.

This functionality copies create parameters of the existing one (which parameters you could modify) and creates new connector.